# Erro de sintaxe no Java JDBC MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou com um erro de sintaxe aqui na query do mySql dentro do código Java, no repositorio. O erro é tanto no método ALTERAR como também no EXCLUIr.

```
package com.leporonitech.agenda.repositorios.impl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.leporonitech.agenda.entidades.Contato;
import com.leporonitech.agenda.fabricas.FabricaConexaoJdbc;
import com.leporonitech.repositorios.interfaces.AgendaRepositorio;

public class ContatoRepositorioJdbc implements AgendaRepositorio<Contato> {

    @Override
    public List<Contato> selecionar() throws SQLException, IOException {

        List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();
        try (Connection conexao = FabricaConexaoJdbc.criarConexao()) {
            Statement comando = conexao.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contatos");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Contato contato = new Contato();
                contato.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                contato.setIdade(rs.getInt("idade"));
                contato.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                contato.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                contatos.add(contato);
            }
        }
        return contatos;
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(Contato entidade) throws SQLException, IOException {
        Connection conexao = null;
        try {
            conexao = FabricaConexaoJdbc.criarConexao();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO contatos (nome, idade, telefone) " + " VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            comando.setString(1, entidade.getNome());
            comando.setInt(2, entidade.getIdade());
            comando.setString(3, entidade.getTelefone());
            comando.execute();
        } finally {
            if (conexao != null) {
                conexao.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(Contato entidade) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Connection conexao = null;
        try {
            conexao = FabricaConexaoJdbc.criarConexao();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement("UPDATE contatos SET nome=?, idade=?, telefone=?");
            comando.setString(1, entidade.getNome());
            comando.setInt(2, entidade.getIdade());
            comando.setString(3, entidade.getTelefone());
            comando.execute();
        } finally {
            if (conexao != null) {
                conexao.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Contato entidade) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Connection conexao = null;
        try {
            conexao = FabricaConexaoJdbc.criarConexao();
            PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM contatos (nome, idade, telefone)");
            comando.setString(1, entidade.getNome());
            comando.setInt(2, entidade.getIdade());
            comando.setString(3, entidade.getTelefone());
            comando.execute();
        } finally {
            if (conexao != null) {
                conexao.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace do erro, assim, poderemos lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Em ambos os casos você precisar indicar na sua `query` qual será o Contato (no seu caso) que será alterado ou excluído, seja o `nome` ou até mesmo um `id`. Será necessário você passar como parâmetro dessas suas funções um indicador que será utilizado na sua `query` com o comando `WHERE`. Este link poderá lhe ajudar https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-tutorial-sql-insert-select-update-and-delete-examples

Comment: Nos dois percebi que você não colocou o WHERE, então alteraria tudo e excluiria tudo, é isso que você quer?